# Преобразовать Dictionary из контроллера в Array JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, fetch

В контроллере такой код:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var titles = _context.Post.Skip(Math.Max(0, _context.Post.Count() - 3));

            Dictionary<int, string> icons = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                {1, "https://psv4.userapi.com/c856216/u255728013/docs/d4/25a0121ef7e0/icons8-patreon-24.png?extra=iIg5FaXfLQhNTl2Tis4nHFwBNf8axTD_FzWCXXoE5SUkcnUYQw_y0e89lG_jKelKLPLyMPezCAOrlpowROFLbqWs9d5tADacKUpT2XJIn1o9Z1j-ngQ2I2a-eWM8R4b2jueZnSxsWedLgQpiN1OcjbRBWg" },
                {2, "https://psv4.userapi.com/c856528/u255728013/docs/d14/452cd2130b88/blog.svg?extra=6rkAwH-8jQYkHEfJcYuRo34NcBA1ydm_DkggZrbs3pG9Y_Lgcd7BmLYB_xJHx2_qHUS-I_2v8YitH5I3_JnNk0RizKCzKg3NwcDzWkH_kX2RDoIB7dDqUjxt1MzFIFRI-t4DJfaKBAJlUI7sfj07TFO37Q&dl=1"},
                {3, "https://psv4.userapi.com/c856216/u255728013/docs/d4/25a0121ef7e0/icons8-patreon-24.png?extra=iIg5FaXfLQhNTl2Tis4nHFwBNf8axTD_FzWCXXoE5SUkcnUYQw_y0e89lG_jKelKLPLyMPezCAOrlpowROFLbqWs9d5tADacKUpT2XJIn1o9Z1j-ngQ2I2a-eWM8R4b2jueZnSxsWedLgQpiN1OcjbRBWg" }

            };

            List<PostsPayload> articles = new List<PostsPayload>();

            foreach (var title in titles)
            {
                articles.Add(new PostsPayload
                {
                    IconUrl = icons[title.ResourceId],
                    AtricleBody = title.Title
                }) ;
            }
            return Json(articles.ToArray());
        }
```

В классе React js этот код:

```
export class BlockBuilder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { blocktitle: "", data: [] };        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    async fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch('api/article');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ blocktitle: this.props.blocktitle, data: data });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="newsblock_blockHead">
                    <div className="blockText">{this.state.blocktitle}</div></div>
                <div className="newsblock_body pr-0">
                    <ArticleBuilder data={this.state.data} />
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

class ArticleBuilder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
        this.setState = { data: this.props.data };
    }

    render() {
        var links = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.data.length; i++) {
            var item = this.props.data[i];
            links.push(
                <div className="article" key={i}>
                    <img src={item.IconUrl} className="article_image" />
                    <p className="paragraph">
                        <a href={"#"}>{item.ArticleBody}</a>
                    </p>

                </div>
            );
        }
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {links}
            </React.Fragment>

        );
    }
}
```

Response

```
    [{"iconUrl":"https://psv4.userapi.com/c856216/u255728013/docs/d4/25a0121ef7e0/icons8-patreon-24.png?extra=iIg5FaXfLQhNTl2Tis4nHFwBNf8axTD_FzWCXXoE5SUkcnUYQw_y0e89lG_jKelKLPLyMPezCAOrlpowROFLbqWs9d5tADacKUpT2XJIn1o9Z1j-ngQ2I2a-eWM8R4b2jueZnSxsWedLgQpiN1OcjbRBWg","atricleBody":"October\u0027s project 2B Nier Automata RE!"},{"iconUrl":"https://psv4.userapi.com/c856216/u255728013/docs/d4/25a0121ef7e0/icons8-patreon-24.png?extra=iIg5FaXfLQhNTl2Tis4nHFwBNf8axTD_FzWCXXoE5SUkcnUYQw_y0e89lG_jKelKLPLyMPezCAOrlpowROFLbqWs9d5tADacKUpT2XJIn1o9Z1j-ngQ2I2a-eWM8R4b2jueZnSxsWedLgQpiN1OcjbRBWg","atricleBody":"September phone wallpaper #2 [Hidden treasure pt. 2]"},{"iconUrl":"https://psv4.userapi.com/c856528/u255728013/docs/d14/452cd2130b88/blog.svg?extra=6rkAwH-8jQYkHEfJcYuRo34NcBA1ydm_DkggZrbs3pG9Y_Lgcd7BmLYB_xJHx2_qHUS-I_2v8YitH5I3_JnNk0RizKCzKg3NwcDzWkH_kX2RDoIB7dDqUjxt1MzFIFRI-t4DJfaKBAJlUI7sfj07TFO37Q\u0026dl=1","atricleBody":"Vacation time! Interesting stories inside!"}]
```

Идея такая: из БД вытащить titles, сопоставить с нужными иконками и вернуть в массив KeyValue в js коде, а затем занести его в state. Потом сделать map и вернуть элементы. 
Не понимаю, почему не срабатывает правильно фетч, пробовал возвращать и просто Dictionary, и JsonConvert.Seralize(articles), но всё равно ошибки. Во вкладке Network браузера нашел запрос к article, но там в response вообще идет html-код index.html почему-то.

UPD: сейчас дошёл хотя бы до того, что получаю нормальный ответ с сервера виде json, однако элементы все равно не отображаются. Что я делаю не так?
В links хранится три Object с IconUrl и ArticleBody, если что. PostsPayload - модель, в которой есть одноименные свойства

Comment: напишите массив данных, который у вас прилетает при запросе `fetch('api/article')` и тогда думаю вам быстрее смогут помочь с решением

Comment: @MasterAlex попробовал сам кое-что сделать, но все еще не получается. Обновил пост

Answer (score 0):

По итогу проблема чрезвычайно глупая. После редактирования кода все почти получилось, но не работало. А не работало потому что не учел, что при конвертации в Json, названия превращаются в camelCase, судя по всему
И была опечатка в ArticleBody

Прошу прощения за глупость такую